# OutputCache has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, outputcache, 51degrees

I'm back on a MVC app where I thought that output caching was working as expected. However, while revisiting it, I see that the OutputCache attribute I use has no effect (Duration is set to a high value). Whether I add it or not, the breakpoint in my action is always hit and Firebug shows me a 200 OK on the requested page in each case.

In a more complex action where I use VaryByCustom, the GetVaryByCustomString method in global.asax is never called. I know that it was called in the past since I was able to debug there but now it's not.

I wonder what I did to break this... Any idea?

(in order to not only test localhost, I use a dyndns.org address so that it's a valid external URL. I also use IIS).

**Update**: when I use the localhost URL, targetting the same url does not enter the action code again. Hitting F5 does. When using the internet URL it always visits the action code.

**Update 2**: Fiddler is showing this in the response headers:

```
200 OK

Cache:
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=86400
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 19:38:46 GMT
Expires: Tue, 17 Jul 2012 19:38:46 GMT
Vary: *
```

Expires = Date + 24h each time I request the same url, which shows that a new page is served each time. Also I should get 200 the first time and 304 thereafter.

Comment: Is the OutputCache attribute applied at the controller level or the action level?

Comment: It is applied at the action level.

Comment: Use fiddler to test caching and make sure web.config reflect release

Comment: @RickAndMSFT updated answer. I don't know what else to investigate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered the culprit, which is contextual to my application:

If I remove the 51degrees.mobi nuget package from my app, it just works again. Put it back (even without using its features) and caching is dead. Well, in fact there are 2 cases:

- If you just add the package, **GetVaryByCustomString is never called**. The action method is called once correctly and then is served from the cache.
- If you add the package AND you also use a CompressFilter attribute, then **GetVaryByCustomString is never called AND the action method is always called (no page served from the cache)**.

I posted to their forums to report this issue.

***Update***: these issues appear starting with 51degrees version 2.1.4.9. I notice that this is the first version using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, in case this is relevant...

***Update 2***: they found the cause of this issue and it will be fixed.

Comment: Just ran into this exact problem as I was adding caching to an old app that was using an old version of this package. I can't imagine how I would have ever traced my problem back to 51degrees.mobi without you.

Comment: @BrianCauthon I'm glad it helped Brian!